# How Ubuntu can resolve the 'localhost' address without any webserver installed?

Tags: apache2, lamp

I decided to install a LAMP stack and follow this [nice tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP).
I removed everything apache2,mySQL,php related using apt-get and the --purge option (as the tutorial said).

A reboot later I have no more apache2 service or daemon on my machine:

```
julien@shittyLaptop:~$ sudo service apache2 stop
apache2: unrecognized service
```

and

```
julien@shittyLaptop:/etc/init.d$ ls|grep apa
julien@shittyLaptop:/etc/init.d$
```

Cool... except: now, if I go to h**p://localhost, **it still displays the "It Works" page**.
If I modify the /var/www/index.html file, firefox displays the change I made!

So, OK sounds somehow logical since I don't need a webserver to display a simple HTML file in FF but:

1) how does Ubuntu know which folder to point to when I enter the localhost address in 
my browser?
2) Is it a normal behaviour and could I go on with actually installing a LAMP stack? Or do you think something is corrupted on this install?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu JulienC! It is always encouraged to [answer your own question](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) since you've solved the problem (I think you'll have to wait another 8 hours though).

Answer (score 2):

Quote from OP:

> An obscure webserver, tntnet (shipped with freemind), was listening on port 80, preventing apache to start.

---

Now, how to discover this? With the use of `sudo lsof -i:80 | grep LISTEN`:

```
braiam@bt:~$ sudo lsof -i:80 | grep LISTEN
nginx     4412     root    6u  IPv4 753652      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     4412     root    7u  IPv6 753653      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     4414 www-data    6u  IPv4 753652      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     4414 www-data    7u  IPv6 753653      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     4415 www-data    6u  IPv4 753652      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     4415 www-data    7u  IPv6 753653      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     4416 www-data    6u  IPv4 753652      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     4416 www-data    7u  IPv6 753653      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     4417 www-data    6u  IPv4 753652      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx     4417 www-data    7u  IPv6 753653      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

As you can see, I have nginx runing in the http (80) port. There are other options like the use of `netstat`.

Comment: Thanks, great info.I was a little bit tired/upset at the moment, and I'm sure tntnet is a nice project, and not just 'an obscure webserver' :)